# "Идет прием заявок(,) до 15 января"

Tags: пунктуация

"Идет прием заявок, до 15 января". Нужна ли запятая?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Причин для постановки запятой нет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35674/discussion-on-answer-by-------1).

Answer (score 1):

"Идет прием заявок, до 15 января".

Написать так можно (с точки зрения грамматики), обособив обстоятельство с уточняющим значением, но это будет **разговорный стиль,** который обычно не используется в подобных объявлениях.

В этом случае подойдет такой вариант (**деловой стиль**): *Прием заявок проводится до 15 января.*

Comment: Уточнение — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому. Здесь нет другого об-ва, которое бы сужалось об-вом ''до 15 января".  Иначе произойдет отрыв обстоятельства от глагола. Запятая не зависит от разговорного стиля.

Comment: 1) УТОЧНЕНИЕ — это переход от более широкого понятия к более узкому. Но это грамматическое (узкое) значение  уточнения. В общем же случае уточнением  (или присоединительным членом со значением уточнения, пояснения и т.д.) можно назвать член предложения, содержащий   дополнительную информацию.   2)  ЗАПЯТАЯ здесь обозначает  не стиль, а обособление обстоятельства, но вот подобная структура предложения (с обособленным обстоятельством)  соответствует  свободной, разговорной манере, а не деловому стилю.

Comment: А нас и интересует грамматическое уточнение. Вряд ли от запятой может поменяться структура предложения. Исходя из вашей трактовки, можно обособить любое обязательство. Пр.: Увидимся завтра в 9  часов. Получается, и здесь можно поставить запятую.

Comment: Серж, семантика управляет формой, а не наоборот. Если мне нужно выразить  уточнение, я подбираю подходящую форму, с помощью которой это можно сделать.  В разговорном стиле можно сказать: "Идет прием заявок, до 15 января".  Без запятой это вообще неграмотное предложение. Возможен еще один вариант: Идет прием заявок (до 15 января). Имеется в виду: он будет проходить до 15 января.

Comment: Предложение стилистически некорректно, согласен. И оттого, если поставить запятую, оно не станет грамотнее и не приобретет разговорную окраску. Запятые надо ставить, исходя из структуры предложения, а не стиля, как говорите вы. Поэтому лучше оставить предложенный вами вариант:Идет прием заявок (до 15 января).

Comment: Да не говорю я, что запятые зависят от стиля. Поймите автора, его предложение содержит два сообщения: 1) сейчас идет прием заявок; 2) он продлится до 15 января. И стоит задача: найти подходящую грамматическую форму. В устной речи можно просто сделать паузу, вот этот вариант с паузой и записан, где остановка в речи обозначена запятой. Но для письменного объявления (деловой стиль) устный/разговорный  вариант нехорош, хотя он может быть записан. Поэтому пытаемся подобрать письменную форму, где обе ситуации будут отражены (что запись уже идет и что она продлится до определенного срока).

Comment: Вряд ли обособление обстоятельства как-то связано с разговорным стилем. Здесь просто обособление не требуется в принципе, подобное возможно только если автору уж очень важно выделить хоть чем-то именно дату. Не знаю, какой уж это стиль, наверное просто авторский. В остальном, пожалуй, соглашусь.

Answer (score 1):

Слово *идёт* в этом объявлении лишнее, т. к. стоит «впереди лошади». Краткие объявления вполне обходятся без глаголов. Кажущаяся здесь правильной запятая отобьёт глагол от обстоятельства времени, что недопустимо. Можно, оправдывая такую необычную конструкцию, объяснить её тем, что автор текста намеренно сдвинул последние два члена, имея в виду «заявки до 15 января».

Comment: Если убрать глагол, то нужно ли ставить тире? **Прием заявок - до 15 января.** По-моему, что-то подобное уже обсуждалось, но не могу  найти где.

Comment: По желанию исполнителя и выбору формата баннера или картона возможны варианты в одну строку и (в две и три) столбиком. В первом случае тире необходимо тире.